# Missing Template error in RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made this update button on the edit post page, but when clicked on, it directs to this "missing templates" error page. 
I checked on google and stack overflow, but all of the answers are code specific.
hence I am not able to find the appropriate solution.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK0Np.png)

> Missing template posts/update, application/update with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb,
>   :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *
>   "c:/Sites/myrubyblog/app/views"

Comment: What is the actual problem you have ?

Comment: On update dear you have to redirect some where. There will be now vies for the update method.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `update` action is empty rails expects to find a template with same name and fails - hence the error page. Usually this action saves data and redirects or renders `edit` again on validation error

So either create a template or make action to redirect/render

Comment: When making the update action, it should update attributes and save before redirecting. I think adding that will help the questioner since he's a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

This error might have occurred because the rails is not able to find the update view in the "c:/Sites/myrubyblog/app/views" , as we don't use a view page for update action we usually give a `redirect_to` for a particular page after `update_attributes`

So, if you could give a redirect after saving the updation you can resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have :method => "Post" on your button. And make sure you have a redirect on your update action